# How to get the final result of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with a lot of javascript code, for example the content of a div depends on length of an array :

```
for (var i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) {
   document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('h2')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('title: ' + movieList[i].title));
    var cUL = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].rating));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].year));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].length));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode(movieList[i].isComedy));
    cUL.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('main characters: ' + movieList[i].mainCharacters.join(", ")));
}
```

I am using these perl `LWPx::ParanoidAgent` and `HTML::TokeParser` modules to handle the HTML code but the i want the result of the javascript script

Comment: and what is the question ????

Comment: What do you mean by `want the result of the javascript`? The result is the appended elements.

Comment: Do you mean `$(window).on('load',function(){alert($('body').html());});` ???

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, i need to have a full html text, with the result of javascript in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to:

1. Reverse engineer the JS and apply the changes it would make manually *or*
2. Run the HTML and JS through a browser or browser-like tool and read the data from its DOM

There are a number of options for the latter, including [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox), [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aSelenium) and [Wight](https://metacpan.org/module/Wight).

Answer (score -1):

perhaps https://getfirebug.com/ is what you're looking for. Amongst loads of other things you can view your HTML *after* JavaScript has altered it.